# LINQ API Clarifications

Tags: c#, linq

I know Microsoft Implementation of LINQ.Are Different LINQ APIs  availabe (third party)?

Comment: What do you *exactly* mean by LINQ? It's a broad term that covers a bunch of related but distinct features (language extensions, libraries, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

[LINQ to Twitter](http://www.codeplex.com/LinqToTwitter)

[LINQ to Excel](http://www.codeplex.com/xlslinq)

[LINQ To Everything Else](http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/02/28/link-to-everything-a-list-of-linq-providers.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly different LINQ providers around. For example, there's [LINQ to NHibernate](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQToNHibernate.ashx); I have [Push LINQ](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/01/04/quot-push-quot-linq-revisited-next-attempt-at-an-explanation.aspx); there's a [.NET 2.0-compatible port of LINQ to Objects](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/), and various others.

One of the nice things about LINQ is that it's more of a pattern than anything else. You can implement the bits of the pattern that are useful to you, in whatever way you want. If you want an out-of-process query engine then you can use `Queryable` to start with, but you don't *have* to use either `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`.